# Is there any better solution to reverse uniq count

Tags: bash, count, reverse, uniq

I want to reverse the `uniq -c` output from:

> ```
>   1 hi
>   2 test
>   3 try
> ```

to:

```
hi
test  
test  
try  
try  
try
```

My solution now is to use a loop:

```
while read a b; do yes $b |head -n $a ;done <test.txt
```

I wonder if there are any simpler commands to achieve that?

Comment: I think your solution is awesome. Very creative use of `yes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another `awk`

```
awk '{while ($1--) print $2}' file
```

Comment: simplest solution by now, may i ask about '($1--)'?

Comment: this condition returns `$1` and decrease it by one. Similar to other languages that have the `++`,`--` operands, reduction happens after every evaluation. So it counts downwards from `$1` to zero, for every line.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution

```
echo "\
1 hi
2 test
3 try" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=$1;i++){print($2)}}'
```

**output**

```
hi
test
test
try
try
try
```

This will work the same way, with

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=$1;i++){print($2)}}' uniq_counts.txt
```

The core of the script, if of course

```
 { for (i=1;i<=$1;i++) { print $2 }
```

where `awk` has parsed the input into 2 fields, `$1` being the number (1,2,3) and $2 is the value, (hi,test,try).

The condition `i<=$1` tests that the counter `i` has not incremented beyond the count supplied in field $1, and the `print $2` prints the value each time that `i<=$1` condition is true.

IHTH

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `awk` or any other command, you can do it entirely in `bash`

```
while read n s
do
    for ((i=0; i<n; i++))
    do
        echo $s;
    done
done < test.txt
```

Comment: Quote the expansion and you might also want to use `read -r ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Here my solution uses the [bash **brace expansion**](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) and the `printf` internal command.

```
while read a b
do
     eval printf "'%.${#b}s\n'" "'$b'"{1..$a}
done <test.txt
```

The following simple example

```
printf '%s\n' test{1..2}
```

prints two lines which contain the string test followed by a number:

```
test1
test2
```

but we can specify the exact number of characters to print by using the [precision field](http://www.manpages.info/linux/printf.3.html) of the `printf` command:

```
printf '%.4s\n' test{1..2}
```

to display:

```
test
test
```

The length of the characters to print is given by the length of the text to print (`${#b}`).

Finally the `eval` command must be used in other to use variables in the brace expansion.